# transition background overlay on hover

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions, transition

Been googling this for an hour and can't find the answer. Can one of you guys help me please? 
It's mostly doing everything I want, but i want to transition the overlay, rather than having it snap in and out. I also want to be able to scale the icon slightly in the same action. More than open to jquery if needed. Thanks in advance. 
Code snippet attached.

```css
.leftPanel {
  background-color: #fb5757;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
.leftPanel:hover {
  background-image: url("http://www.soundtrackgeek.com/_WebThemes/pixelation/assets/images/fancybox/fancybox-overlay.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.rightPanel {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.rightPanel:hover {
  background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7ddmFBemMJY/UZy726LC2LI/AAAAAAAAC7w/WcwIHoWSSRU/s1600/hex-grid-overlay.png);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.texts {
  display: inline-block;
}
.texts img {
  display: inline;
  width: 60%;
  margin-top: 45%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="leftPanel">
  <div class="texts">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.globalbrigades.org/media_gallery/thumb/320/0/Dental_2014_Icon_Small.png">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="rightPanel">
  <div class="texts">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://www.globalbrigades.org/media_gallery/thumb/320/0/Engineering_2014_Icon_Small.png" id="dev-text">
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did your search for `CSS transition` bring up [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions)? Or [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition)?

Comment: I did, but it all fell apart when trying to transition a bg image

Comment: One gotcha when you get it working is getting the transform far enough up the dom tree so it transforms out as well as in. Good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done playing a bit with pseudo-elements (`:before` and `:after`).

Relevant CSS:

```
.leftPanel:after, .rightPanel:after {
  content: "";
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 1s;
}
.leftPanel:after{
  background-image: url("http://www.soundtrackgeek.com/_WebThemes/pixelation/assets/images/fancybox/fancybox-overlay.png");
}
.rightPanel:after{
  background-image: url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-7ddmFBemMJY/UZy726LC2LI/AAAAAAAAC7w/WcwIHoWSSRU/s1600/hex-grid-overlay.png);
}
.leftPanel:hover:after, .rightPanel:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.texts{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

CHECK: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/7pnatg52/2/

Comment: That will do it. Thank you!